# How to access "Open with/Save" dialog to catch the download link?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, xul, preference

I have noticed that: If the Mozilla Firefox user clicks on download link (**EX**: [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/goldendict/files/goldendict/1.0/goldendict-1.0.1-src.tar.bz2/download?use_mirror=garr)), the following "Open with/Save" dialog window will pop up:

[image: Open with/ Save dialog]

I have download manager named `rd` written in Python, So I need to:

1. Catch the download link from Firefox.
2. Send it to my download manager.

I want to achieve that by any method of the following:

- Add checkbox to that dialog enabling the user to use my download manager in this link (as DTA and flashgot add thier checkboxes).
- Listen for that event ( save dialog pop up),
- Add my download manager named **rd** as a default application for any file type other than `html` but We should give the user the ability to `add to/remove from` that file types send to my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is handled by Firefox's MIME type handling and can be configured by editing [MimeTypes.rdf](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf). I don't think there is a way to handle all but a certain type, rather it seems you have to explicitly enable your app for every MIME type you wish to handle.

Here's an example of setting the handler of `.png` files to your rd program.

```
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:image/png"
                   NC:fileExtensions="png"
                   NC:description="PNG Image"
                   NC:value="image/png"
                   NC:editable="true">
    <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:image/png"/>
  </RDF:Description>

  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:handler:image/png"
                   NC:alwaysAsk="false"
                   NC:saveToDisk="false"
                   NC:useSystemDefault="false"
                   NC:handleInternal="false">
    <NC:externalApplication RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:externalApplication:image/png"/>
  </RDF:Description>

  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:externalApplication:image/png"
                   NC:path="[PATH TO rd]"
                   NC:prettyName="rd" />
```

As for enabling the user to change the default handler to something else, this is already enabled in Firefox's preferences (Preferences->Applications).

Comment: Where you install your rd app to.

Comment: what is the path of mimetype.rdf ??

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. It varies depending on profiles. A given user can have multiple Firefox profiles. You can find them in `C:/Users/[Username]/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/[Profile Name]/mimeTypes.rdf` on Windows and `/home/[Username]/.mozilla/firefox/[Profile Name]/mimeTypes.rdf` on Linux.

Comment: Maybe this link can help to find the profile directory. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Code_snippets%253AFile_I_O#Getting_files_in_special_directories